# How to escape $ in a Visual Studio Project command / property value

Tags: visual-studio

I want to create a custom build command in my Visual Studio project that uses a $ sign in it, e.g.

```
echo $(SomethingIDontWantExpanded) > MyFile
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get `$(SomethingIDontWantExpanded)` in the file, it always puts in an empty string (because it tries to expand it as a variable). I have tried `$$(SomethingIDontWantExpanded)`, `\$(SomethingIDontWantExpanded)`, ...

Comment: Have you tried just using `SomethingIDontWantExpanded`? Visual Studio defines marcos using the $: `$(marco)`, so you don't want to use `$`.

Comment: I actually want a $ in the resulting file. I expect the contents of MyFile to be '$(SomethingIDontWantExpanded)' (without the quotes)